# Aut($G$) $\simeq$ Aut($M$) $ \times$ Aut($N$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A question in group theory:

Let $ G = M \times N $ be the direct product of $ 2 $ normal subgroups.
If $( | M | , | N | ) = 1 $ then Aut($G$) $\simeq$ Aut($M$) $ \times$ Aut($N$).
I proved that Aut($M$) $ \times$ Aut($N$) $\le$ Aut($G$), but I can't prove the other inclusion. Any hint ?

Comment: How far did you get with the proof in the other direction?

Comment: This answers your question, since it proves that the subgroups $M,N$ are characteristic: [if $(|N|,[G:N])=1$, then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $|N|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364847/if-n-gn-1-then-g-has-a-unique-subgroup-of-order-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Lagrange's theorem tells you you aren't going to have any $\phi\in\text{Aut}(G)$ move anything in $N$ to anything in $M$ and vice versa.  Thus we expect we can describe an automorphism in $\text{Aut}(G)$ by what it does to each of the direct factors - we want each $\phi$ to be written $\psi_M\times \psi_N$, where $(\psi_M\times\psi_N)(m,n)=(\psi_M(m),\psi_N(n))$.  Now, given a $\phi$, how could we figure out what $\psi_M$ and $\psi_N$ are?

> Consider $\phi(m,1)$.  Where does that map to? What about $\phi(1,n)$?  Remember that $M,N$ are normal and coprime, so they are characteristic Sylow subgroups of $M\times N$. Now what about $\phi(m,n)$?

Comment: You need to deal with the possibility that elements of $N$ (or $M$) are sent somwhere that *isn't* in $N$ or $M$.

Comment: $N,M$ are characteristic in $G$ since they are by assumption normal and coprime to their index.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber, well, that is «dealing with the possibility» :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well, there ya go then. :)

Comment: In the spoiler you wrote they are Sylow subgroups. This is irrelevant, and not necessarily true.

Comment: @AnneBauval Been a few years. I must have meant that they're Hall subgroups. Not sure why I brought that up either-- setting the scene, I guess?