# if $(|N|,[G:N])=1$, then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $|N|$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a finite groupe and $N\lhd G$ s.t. $(|N|,[G:N])=1$. Show that $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $|N|$.

To be honnest, I don't really understand the question... would it be that $N$ is the only subgroup of order $|N|$ ? If yes :

**Attempts**

Let $K\lhd G$ s.t. $|K|=|N|$. Suppose there is $h\in K$ s.t. $h\notin N$. In particular, $hN\neq N$ and $h^{[G:N]}N=H$, how can I continue ?

Comment: You should not assume that $K$ is normal. A hint for a way to show this: Consider the subgroup $HK$ and what the possible order of that is.

Comment: What does $N\lhd G$ mean? Does it mean $N$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: @Naive: Yes of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$N$ is the only subgroup of order $|N|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489199/n-is-the-only-subgroup-of-order-n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K$ be another subgroup of $G$ such that $ |K| = |N| $ , then since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ , therefore $NK$ will also be a subgroup of $G$.

$|NK| = (|N||K|)/|N \cap K|$

But since $NK$ is a subgroup of G therefore by Lagrange's theorem $|NK|$ divides $|G|$ which from above equation implies $|N| = |K| = |N \cap K|$ (since $(|N| , [G:N]) = 1$ ) Hence $ N = K $  , that is $N$ is unique subgroup of order $|N|$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Nice first post!

Comment: but since $N\cap K\leq N$ and $N\cap K\leq K$, we get that $N=K=N\cap K$, no ?