# Proving that in $G=H\times K$ where $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$ the subgroups $(H\times \{1\})$ and$(\{1\}\times K)$ are characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have a direct product of two groups: $G=H\times K$, where $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$ or $H$ and $K$ are coprime. We have to show that $(H\times\{1\})$ and $(\{1\}\times K)$ are $\underline{characteristic}$ in $G$, that is: a subgroup $S$ in a group $A$ is characteristic if and only if, $\forall \phi \in Aut(A)\;\phi(S)=S$. The theory given before this exercise can be summarized in the following results: $1]$ Given $X,Y\trianglelefteq Z$, such that $X\cap Y=\{1\}$, it holds $xy=yx\;\forall x\in X,\forall y\in Y$ $\;2]$(Direct product decomposition) Given $X,Y\trianglelefteq Z$, such that $(X\cap Y=\{1\})$ and $(XY=Z)$, it holds $G\simeq X\times Y$ $\;3]$ Given a group $G_{3}$ and two abritrary subgroups $G_{1},G_{2}$, we can consider the direct product $G=G_{1}\times G_{2}$ and the subgroups of $G$ $H=G_{1}\times\{1\},K=\{1\}\times G_{2}$; it holds $G\simeq H\times K$ by $2]$. I think $3]$ has to be used, and I'm sure $(H\times \{1\})$ and $(\{1\}\times K)$ are normal exactly by $3]$ (characteristic$\rightarrow$normal, so at least I have they're normal), but I honestly don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if $(|N|,[G:N])=1$, then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $|N|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364847/if-n-gn-1-then-g-has-a-unique-subgroup-of-order-n)

Comment: I read the question and did not understand how I could use that to prove those subgroups are characteristic.

Comment: Let us denote $H\times \{1\}$ by $H$ for short. $\forall\phi\in Aut(G)\quad\phi(H)$ is a subgroup of order $|H|$ but the only one is $H.$ Same for $K.$

Comment: That seems correct, but how to translate the hypothesis that $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$ to the hypothesis that $gcd(|G|,[G:H])=1$ and $gcd(|G|,[G:K])=1$? If I'm not mistaken we also used $3]$ to get that $H,K$ were normal in $G$.

Comment: That (and the 3 duplicates) *are* correct. The hypothesis is satisfied because $[G:H]=|K|.$ (Btw, $\gcd(|G|,[G:H])=[G:H],$ not $1$.) The factors of a direct product are obviously normal (3 is off topic).